# Problem with calculating quantile for a number series using data table in R

Tags: r, datatable, quantile

I need to calculate the quantile for a number series in data table R for each row in data table.

```
Table:  

       2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019
         NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
       11.7 10.7 10.8 11.8 12.2 13.8  7.0 10.2 11.2  6.8  7.4  9.1  9.5  9.4  9.3 15.6 11.3 13.0 10.9 10.5
         NA   NA  9.5 11.3 16.6 12.2   NA   NA 69.6   NA   NA 12.4 10.8 10.5  8.8  9.9   NA  7.7 12.1   NA
        9.1  8.7 29.9 23.1 18.3 23.5 21.5 23.0 18.2 28.8 39.9 16.4 16.9 23.4 18.8 31.9 26.2 22.4 29.2 25.2
       14.7 17.5 21.1 19.4 20.0 14.5 14.1 12.6  9.9 12.6  6.4  9.6 18.5 14.3 26.2 10.7  6.4  6.9  7.1  9.0
```

I want to calculate quantile for each row of Table above. Please see my code below but I need to place the values for each row as shown in "Output".

```
year_cols <- c(2000:2019) 
Table[, c("10","25","50","75","100") := quantile(.SD, na.rm = TRUE, c(0.1,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0)), .SDcols = as.character(year_cols)]
```

How can I calculate quantile values for each row as shown below or I appreciate if anyone can help to revise my code so that I can show quantile values for each row using data table R.

```
Output:

2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 10%  25%  50%  75%  100% 
  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA  NA   NA   NA   NA
11.7 10.7 10.8 11.8 12.2 13.8  7.0 10.2 11.2  6.8  7.4  9.1  9.5  9.4  9.3 15.6 11.3 13.0 10.9 10.5 7.36 9.37 10.75 11.72 15.60 
  NA   NA  9.5 11.3 16.6 12.2   NA   NA 69.6   NA   NA 12.4 10.8 10.5  8.8  9.9   NA  7.7 12.1   NA
 9.1  8.7 29.9 23.1 18.3 23.5 21.5 23.0 18.2 28.8 39.9 16.4 16.9 23.4 18.8 31.9 26.2 22.4 29.2 25.2
14.7 17.5 21.1 19.4 20.0 14.5 14.1 12.6  9.9 12.6  6.4  9.6 18.5 14.3 26.2 10.7  6.4  6.9  7.1  9.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to group by row

```
year_cols <- as.character(2000:2019)
Table[, c("10%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%") := 
   as.list(quantile(unlist(.SD), na.rm = TRUE, 
       c(0.1,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0))), by = seq_len(nrow(Table)), 
        .SDcols = year_cols]
Table
#   2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019   10%
#1:   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#2: 11.7 10.7 10.8 11.8 12.2 13.8  7.0 10.2 11.2  6.8  7.4  9.1  9.5  9.4  9.3 15.6 11.3 13.0 10.9 10.5  7.36
#3:   NA   NA  9.5 11.3 16.6 12.2   NA   NA 69.6   NA   NA 12.4 10.8 10.5  8.8  9.9   NA  7.7 12.1   NA  8.87
#4:  9.1  8.7 29.9 23.1 18.3 23.5 21.5 23.0 18.2 28.8 39.9 16.4 16.9 23.4 18.8 31.9 26.2 22.4 29.2 25.2 15.67
#5: 14.7 17.5 21.1 19.4 20.0 14.5 14.1 12.6  9.9 12.6  6.4  9.6 18.5 14.3 26.2 10.7  6.4  6.9  7.1  9.0  6.85
#      25%   50%    75% 100%
#1:     NA    NA     NA   NA
#2:  9.375 10.75 11.725 15.6
#3:  9.800 11.05 12.250 69.6
#4: 18.275 23.05 26.850 39.9
#5:  9.450 13.35 17.750 26.2
```

---

Anotherr way is `rowQuantiles` from `matrixStats` after converting to `matrix`

```
library(matrixStats)
Table[, c("10%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%") := 
    as.data.frame(rowQuantiles(as.matrix(.SD), na.rm = TRUE,
     probs = c(0.1,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0))), .SDcols = as.character(year_cols)]



Table
#   2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019   10%
#1:   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#2: 11.7 10.7 10.8 11.8 12.2 13.8  7.0 10.2 11.2  6.8  7.4  9.1  9.5  9.4  9.3 15.6 11.3 13.0 10.9 10.5  7.36
#3:   NA   NA  9.5 11.3 16.6 12.2   NA   NA 69.6   NA   NA 12.4 10.8 10.5  8.8  9.9   NA  7.7 12.1   NA  8.87
#4:  9.1  8.7 29.9 23.1 18.3 23.5 21.5 23.0 18.2 28.8 39.9 16.4 16.9 23.4 18.8 31.9 26.2 22.4 29.2 25.2 15.67
#5: 14.7 17.5 21.1 19.4 20.0 14.5 14.1 12.6  9.9 12.6  6.4  9.6 18.5 14.3 26.2 10.7  6.4  6.9  7.1  9.0  6.85
#      25%   50%    75% 100%
#1:     NA    NA     NA   NA
#2:  9.375 10.75 11.725 15.6
#3:  9.800 11.05 12.250 69.6
#4: 18.275 23.05 26.850 39.9
#5:  9.450 13.35 17.750 26.2
```

#### data

```
Table <- structure(list(`2000` = c(NA, 11.7, NA, 9.1, 14.7), `2001` = c(NA, 
 10.7, NA, 8.7, 17.5), `2002` = c(NA, 10.8, 9.5, 29.9, 21.1), 
     `2003` = c(NA, 11.8, 11.3, 23.1, 19.4), `2004` = c(NA, 12.2, 
     16.6, 18.3, 20), `2005` = c(NA, 13.8, 12.2, 23.5, 14.5), 
     `2006` = c(NA, 7, NA, 21.5, 14.1), `2007` = c(NA, 10.2, NA, 
     23, 12.6), `2008` = c(NA, 11.2, 69.6, 18.2, 9.9), `2009` = c(NA, 
     6.8, NA, 28.8, 12.6), `2010` = c(NA, 7.4, NA, 39.9, 6.4), 
     `2011` = c(NA, 9.1, 12.4, 16.4, 9.6), `2012` = c(NA, 9.5, 
     10.8, 16.9, 18.5), `2013` = c(NA, 9.4, 10.5, 23.4, 14.3), 
     `2014` = c(NA, 9.3, 8.8, 18.8, 26.2), `2015` = c(NA, 15.6, 
     9.9, 31.9, 10.7), `2016` = c(NA, 11.3, NA, 26.2, 6.4), `2017` = c(NA, 
     13, 7.7, 22.4, 6.9), `2018` = c(NA, 10.9, 12.1, 29.2, 7.1
     ), `2019` = c(NA, 10.5, NA, 25.2, 9)), class = c("data.table", 
 "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't want the "Quantile" column but please see the "Output" table. I want the prob values as column headers and quantile values calculated for each row. The quantile values in the 2nd row in the "Output" table were calculated using the values in the second row.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick reply. That was the answer I was looking for.